# How Data and String are treated in graphlab

Tags: pandas, linear-regression, jupyter-notebook, graphlab

I am having large date set in which some of columns are `Date` and other are `categorical Data` like Status, Department Name, Country Name.

So how this data is treated in graphlab when i call the  `graphlab.linear_regression.create` method, does i have to pre-process this data and convert them into numbers or can directly provide to graphlab.

Comment: Any error you faced while doing that?

Comment: @Dark i am trying to  understand how graphlab process the data ? Does it convert string and dates data to categorical values ?

Answer (score 1):

`Graphlab` is mostly used for computing tabular and graph based datasets, and have high `scalability` and `performance`. In `graphlab.linear_regression.create`, `graphlab` have inbuilt feature of understanding the type of data and giving most suitable method of `linear regression` for optimizing results. For Example, for numeric data of target and feature both, most of the time, `graphlab` takes `Newtons Method` of linear regression. Similarly, depending on the dataset, understands the need and gives method accordingly.

Now, about preprocessing, `graphlab` only takes `SFrame` for learning that need to be parsed correctly before any learning. While creating an `SFrame`, unprocessed and error creating data are always reflected and throws an error. So, in order to go through any learning, you need to have a clean data. If `SFrame` accepts the data, and also your chosen target and feature for learning that you want, you are good to go but `pre-processing` and `cleaning data` is always recommended. Also, its always a good practice to do `feature engineering` before any learning algorithm, and redefining data types before learning is always recommended for accuracy.

About your point on how data is treated in `Graphlab`, I would say, it depends!. Some datasets are tabular and are treated accordingly and some in graph structure. Graphlab performs very well when comes to `regression tree` and `boosted classifiers` which follows `decision tree` concept and are quite time and resource consuming in other libraries than `graphlab`.

For me, `graphlab` performed very well while creating recommendation engine where I had dataset of nodes and edges and `boosted tree classifier` with 18 iterations too worked flawless in quite scalable time and I must say, even for tree structured data, `graphlab` performs very well. I hope this answer helps.